# Android: Return the radius of a circle?

Tags: java, android

I created a custom view class that allows the user to draw a circle on the canvas. The circle is drawn with drawCircle and the radius is measured by location of pointers. Now in the activity that displays the circle, I want to send the radius of the circle to another activity and then do some calculations on it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, the user will draw a circle and then click the Done button. The Done button calls this method that will move the application to the next activity:

```
public void goToNext(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, output.class);


}
```

But I don't know how to pass the radius of the circle to the output class

Comment: Get the distance between two opposite sides of the circle (the diameter). Then divide it by 2 to get radius

Answer (score 3):

use `Intent.putExtra` to put any data you want to transfer between activities.
you need to have a keyword that doesn't change so use a final String for it.
in your case it would be something along the lines of

```
public void goToNext(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, output.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_RADIUS, customView.getRadius);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: This is helpful but the getRadius does not work for my custom View for some reason...AndroidStudio says it cannot resolve the getRadius method

Comment: You need to implement that method in your custom view and return the radius value you've drawn with "drawCircle"

Comment: should the getRadius be INSIDE the onDraw method? If I do it that way then  it says "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type"....Here is what I wrote:     public double getRadius(){return radius;};

Comment: when you calculate the radius of the circle put the number in a variable outside `onDraw()` and make a method `getRadius()` that returns that number

Answer (score 1):

You can sent extra data with your intent to the output activity.

```
public void goToNext(View view)
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, output.class);
    intent.putExtra("radius", yourView.getRadius());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in your output.class activity you can access the data with

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("radius", -1); // -1 is the default value
```

More informations: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

Comment: getRadius gives an error in Android studio, cannot resolve. Do you know why that is?

Comment: intent.putExtra("radius", xxx); where xxx is the value of your radius.

Comment: i think the problem here is not passing the radius but getting the radius,  @thequestionasker did u ever get the answer...help me out too